# How to resolve "Principal 'PRINCIPAL_NAME' could not be created." error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sqlcmd

I'm using below sqlcmd command in shell script.

```
sqlcmd -S <SERVER_NAME> -U "<USERNAME>" -P <PASSWORD> -d "<DATABASE>" -q 'CREATE USER [<PRINCIPAL_NAME>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER'
```

but It's giving below error:

```
Msg 33159, Level 16, State 1, Server <SERVER_NAME>, Line 1
Principal '<PRINCIPAL_NAME>' could not be created. Only connections established with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory users.
```

What changes should i make to get it working properly?

Comment: "Only connections established with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory users.". You need to log in with an  AD user not a SQL User

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to  create an Azure AD-based contained database user, we need to login the database with an Azure AD identity which has **ALTER ANY USER** permission. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities)  Besides when we use tool sqlcmd to login database with an Azure AD identity, please add [`-G`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#command-line-options). It used to specify that the user be authenticated using Azure Active Directory authentication.

Regarding how to implement it, please refer to the following steps

1. [Configure  Azure Active Directory authentication with your  SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-ad-authentication-methods).
2. Create contained database users in your database mapped to Azure AD identities

   a. login

   ```
   sqlcmd -S <server name> -d test -U <your SQL Azure AD admin> -P <password> -G
   ```

   b. Create

   ```
   CREATE USER [<PRINCIPAL_NAME>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
   GO
   ```

   [image]